# Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator: ADD, operand type: LIST

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I tried to use ADD in UpdateExpression to add an email string into a string set , code as below , but hit this exception : Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator: ADD, operand type: LIST.

I think the point is that I need a way to change the type into "string set" , but not sure what is the semantic to achieve that.

```
        response = wishesTable.update_item(
            Key={
                'title': wishTitle,
                'userMail': wishUsermail
            },
            UpdateExpression='ADD whoLikeList :my_value',
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ":my_value": [userEmail]
            },
            ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
        )
```

Answer (score 3):

By referring to TypeSerializer class ( http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/boto3/dynamodb/types.html
)

Changing the code to below , it would be treat as set :

```
        response = wishesTable.update_item(
            Key={
                'title': wishTitle,
                'userMail': wishUsermail
            },
            UpdateExpression='ADD whoLikeList :my_value',
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ":my_value": set([userEmail])
            },
            ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
        )
```

Comment: Also note that you need to ensure the field was initially set using `set(list)` rather than just `list` or it will not be able to update it as the attribute in dynamo won't be a set. Updating to use set() fixed it for me too (thanks!), just had to change my initial insert code as well.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me! FYI, you can also use a set literal. `":my_value": {userEmail}` instead of `":my_value": set([userEmail])`.